# How to call tensorflow::NewSession in c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am using c++ to load and run tensorflow graph. The tensorflow version is 2.1 cpu. I have included necessary header files and the libary _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib

I use

```
unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session_inception(tensorflow::NewSession(SessionOptions()));
```

to create a new session. The compiling has no error.

But when I build the executable, there is a link error saying that NewSession is an unresolved external symbol. I guess the function "NewSession" is not in the library file "_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib".

How to call NewSession in c++ environment? or maybe using new APIs to run the graph (instead of using session)? Thank you very much.

Comment: `Session` and `NewSession` are not defined in TensorFlow 2.1. You may to use TensorFlow 1.x instead which is still available to download: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions

Comment: Unresolved external symbols is a common problem on Windows when using TF. But, I don't get it how `_pywrap` is related with c++ library? On Windows, you build TF library by `Bazel` (according official documentation), as output you get two files: import library (`tensorflow_..._.lib`) and dynamic one (`tensorflow_.._.dll`), and in your case you need to rebuild these files adding missing symbols, which can be done in a few seconds.

Comment: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.lib has all the implementations I need except NewSession. I don't want to compile all over again but just want find some way to run the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using this code from 2016: https://gist.github.com/kyrs/9adf86366e9e4f04addb <sub>which I found by googling for "`session_inception`"</sub>. This code predates TensorFlow 2.1 and 2.0 (which was released in September 2019).

The TensorFlow 2.1 documentation does not list any function or type named `Session` or `NewSession` - I'm not a TensorFlow user but I think `ClientSession` is the current type you want.

Here's the sample code from the TensorFlow 2.1 documentation

```
Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
auto a = Placeholder(root, DT_INT32);
auto c = Add(root, a, {41});

ClientSession session(root);
std::vector outputs;

Status s = session.Run({ {a, {1}} }, {c}, &outputs);
if (!s.ok()) { ... }
```

That said, if you want to run this code from March 2016 you should just download the closest version of TensorFlow released around that date, which is version `v0.7.1` available here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v0.7.1 - this is probably inadvisable as TensorFlow's documentation website only has documentation for versions released after v1.0

<sub>As an aside, I assume you're relatively new to working in C++ because I found this information quickly in a matter of seconds - had you done the same you wouldn't have posted this question to SO. If you are inexperienced working with C++ or TensorFlow then I advise you that it would be a bad idea to go wading around obsolete and unsupported C++ libraries as you'll be SOL if anything goes wrong - and things *will* go wrong, especially with prelease versions of TensorFlow.</sub>

Comment: The problem here is how to reuse the existing code without down-grade the tensorflow.

Comment: @JS **You can't reuse the existing code** because the existing code is from 2016 and is **ancient** because it references a prerelease version of TensorFlow with APIs (like `NewSession`) that were removed ages ago. The design of the API surface of TensorFlow has changed a lot from v0.7 in 2016 to today's v2.1 in 2019, so it's impossible to fix it just by changing individual method/API calls. **The code you're using cannot be used today**.